# Visual Studio 2015 sometimes freezes when deploying Xamarin app to device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

This is happening really often to me now, when I try to deploy an Xamarin.Forms (1.4) to my Android device through Visual Studio 2015 it freezes at this point:

[image: deploy]

I have to end the Visual Studio process. If I restart VS and run again it works. After 2-3 times it starts to freeze again and I have to restart again.

Why is this happening? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it actually freezing? Or is it running in the background? I sometimes come across the situation that VS doesn't seem to respond anymore because it is working in the background. You'll notice a VS icon at the icon tray near the clock in your taskbar. Clicking the icon and selecting the 'Bring to front' option actually makes VS responsive again.

Comment: I tried to find if there was any popup or anything blocking the UI but I couldn't find anything. Bring to Front did nothing. And it happened a couple of times just by building the solution (F6)... Are there any logs I could check?

Comment: What you could do is start VS with logging, see; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx also you could try disabling any plugins you might have installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was using the [Design DLLs provided by Xamarin staff here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/142079/#Comment_142079) and they were the culprit causing the issues hanging Visual Studio.

Unfortunately I had to remove them to stop the crashes.